# is there a way to combine tables that have columns with different lengths?

Tags: ms-access, select, union

I have a set of tables that I receive monthly that tell me what a member has paid that month. If they don't pay, they don't show up in the table. I want to figure out how much each member has paid over time. A member may appear in one month's table, but not another. Each table shares an "ID" linked to a member, but because of monthly variability do not all have the same column length. Each table contains a member and the amount of dues that (s)he paid that month.   I am running into a "The number of columns in the two selected tables or queries of a union do not match" error because of this.

Running Access 365, pasted two sets of code:

When I attempt an INNER JOIN, I lose the entries that are not in all tables.

When I attempt a UNION I get an error: "The number of columns in the two selected tables or queries of a union query do not match."

```
SELECT [2018-9 Dues Deduct].ID, [2018-9 Dues Deduct].Name, [2018-9 Dues Deduct].[Curr Dedn], [2018-10 Dues Deduction].[Curr Dedn], [2018-11 Dues Deductions].[Curr Dedn], [2018-12 Dues Deductions].[Curr Dedn]

FROM (([2018-9 Dues Deduct] 

INNER JOIN [2018-10 Dues Deduction] ON [2018-9 Dues Deduct].ID = [2018-10 Dues Deduction].ID) 

INNER JOIN [2018-11 Dues Deductions] ON [2018-10 Dues Deduction].ID = [2018-11 Dues Deductions].ID) 

INNER JOIN [2018-12 Dues Deductions] ON [2018-11 Dues Deductions].ID = [2018-12 Dues Deductions].ID;
```

---

```
SELECT 
  [2018-9 Dues Deduct].ID, 
  [2018-9 Dues Deduct].Name, 
  [2018-9 Dues Deduct].[Curr Dedn], 
  [2018-10 Dues Deduction].[Curr Dedn]
FROM [2018-9 Dues Deduct] 
INNER JOIN [2018-10 Dues Deduction] ON [2018-9 Dues Deduct].ID = [2018-10 Dues Deduction].ID
GROUP BY [2018-9 Dues Deduct].ID, [2018-9 Dues Deduct].Name, [2018-9 Dues Deduct].[Curr Dedn], [2018-10 Dues Deduction].[Curr Dedn]

UNION 
SELECT 
  [2018-10 Dues Deduction].ID, 
  [2018-10 Dues Deduction].Name, 
  [2018-10 Dues Deduction].[Curr Dedn], 
  [2018-11 Dues Deductions].[Curr Dedn]
FROM [2018-10 Dues Deduction] 
INNER JOIN [2018-11 Dues Deductions] ON [2018-10 Dues Deduction].ID = [2018-11 Dues Deductions].ID

UNION 
SELECT 
  [2018-11 Dues Deductions].ID, 
  [2018-11 Dues Deductions].Name, 
  [2018-11 Dues Deductions].[Curr Dedn]
FROM [2018-11 Dues Deductions] 
INNER JOIN [2018-12 Dues Deductions] ON [2018-11 Dues Deductions].ID = [2018-12 Dues Deductions].ID;
```

My goal is to see all deductions (Curr Dedn) from all members (ID), whether or not they paid this month. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error on second posted code fragment? (Because there is union)

the length = number of rows is *no* problem, the number of columns (to union) is your problem. That's what your error says.

I see two reasons:

1. you select different numbers of columns and want to union them - all selects need same columns to get it working
2. You use "group by" - I'm just not sure that this query as standalone give you that many columns as expected - if it does, ignore this part

regarding 1.:
you have 4 columns in first select, 4 in 2nd and only 3 in 3rd.

=> you need a 4th column in your 3rd select. If you have no data, make a dummy.

[update due to comment "works"]:
try this - and I don't know if "dummy" or 'dummy' is correct

```
SELECT 
  [2018-9 Dues Deduct].ID, 
  [2018-9 Dues Deduct].Name, 
  [2018-9 Dues Deduct].[Curr Dedn], 
  [2018-10 Dues Deduction].[Curr Dedn]
FROM [2018-9 Dues Deduct] 
INNER JOIN [2018-10 Dues Deduction] ON [2018-9 Dues Deduct].ID = [2018-10 Dues Deduction].ID
GROUP BY [2018-9 Dues Deduct].ID, [2018-9 Dues Deduct].Name, [2018-9 Dues Deduct].[Curr Dedn], [2018-10 Dues Deduction].[Curr Dedn]

UNION 

SELECT 
  [2018-10 Dues Deduction].ID, 
  [2018-10 Dues Deduction].Name, 
  [2018-10 Dues Deduction].[Curr Dedn], 
  [2018-11 Dues Deductions].[Curr Dedn]
FROM [2018-10 Dues Deduction] 
INNER JOIN [2018-11 Dues Deductions] ON [2018-10 Dues Deduction].ID = [2018-11 Dues Deductions].ID

UNION 

SELECT 
  [2018-11 Dues Deductions].ID, 
  [2018-11 Dues Deductions].Name, 
  [2018-11 Dues Deductions].[Curr Dedn], 
  "dummy" 
FROM [2018-11 Dues Deductions] 
INNER JOIN [2018-12 Dues Deductions] ON [2018-11 Dues Deductions].ID = [2018-12 Dues Deductions].ID;
```

Comment: Yes, the number of rows is the issue for the Union query I believe.

Comment: No, the row number has no effect. you have to few columns in your last select statement - only 3 while the others have 4. And I don't know if the "group by" part works - fix the 4th column first, then we will see.

Comment: that worked! good eye! if I have more tables, who do I need to reproduce?

Comment: nice to read. I would format the query that your long column names are each a line, see my updated answer. and if it worked, please mark the answer as one :)